# Issues writing merge sort with pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error, mergesort

I'm trying to write a merge sort program with pointers, and it is near to working good, but there is the problem that in the output there are some '0' instead of some of the numbers of the sorted array.

For testing the code you have to write a txt file `prova.txt` in which there is the array, one number for line. For example:

prova.txt:

```
4
7
2
9
1
45
87
```

When running the code, I expect the output

```
0: 1 
1: 2
2: 4 
3: 7 
4: 9 
5: 45 
6: 87
```

but I get

```
0: 1 
1: 0 
2: 0 
3: 0 
4: 0 
5: 0 
6: 2
```

Moreover, are there any advice that you can give me for improving my code?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int *merge(int left[], int right[], int n){
      int *ordinato, i=0, j=0;
      ordinato = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
      while(i+j < n){
          if(left[i] < right[j]){
              *(ordinato+i+j) = left[i];
              i++;
          }else{
              *(ordinato+i+j) = right[j];
              j++;
          }
      }
      return ordinato;      
}

int *mergeSort(int *daOrd, int n){
      int k = 0, *left, *right, *ordinato;
      ordinato = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
      left = malloc(sizeof(int)*(n/2));
      right = malloc(sizeof(int)*(n-(n/2)));
      if (n<2){
         ordinato = daOrd;     
      }else{
         for(k=0; k<n/2; k++)
             *(left + k) = *(daOrd + k);
         for(k=n/2; k<n; k++)
             *(right + k -(n/2)) = *(daOrd + k);

         left = mergeSort(left, n/2);
         right = mergeSort(right, n-(n/2));
         ordinato = merge(left, right, n);
      }      
      return ordinato;
}

main(){
     FILE *input;
     input = fopen("prova.txt", "r");
     if(!input) printf("Errore");

     int tot = 100000;//is the maximum n

     int *array;
     array = malloc(sizeof(int)*tot);
     int indice = 0;
     while(fscanf(input,"%d", (array + indice)) != EOF) indice++;

     int *ord = mergeSort(array, indice);

     int k;
     for(k=0; k<indice; k++) printf("%d: %d \n",k,  *(ord+k));


     getch();
     fclose(input);     
}
```

Comment: One advice for readability: Stop trying to write "cool" code. [Always use braces](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no), and rename `daOrd` to something like `array`, `list`, or `base`, and do not obfuscate `left[k]` as `*(left + k)`. Also, you should not allocate memory (you allocate `O(n²)`, although you only need `n`), and `free` it after use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: thank you for your advice. This was the first or maybe the second question on this site, so I don't know this rules.
I just would say that I already used debugger and print-statement, but I put them away because I'm italian and they wouldn't be useful for you, and the code is shorter. Moreover daOrd are 2 italian words, for this motivation I named the array like this. The next time should I rename before uploading the code here?
Oli Charlesworth, where can I find something more about minimal test-case? Your link is for the SSCCE rules...
thank you once again

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This question already contains the whole code, although there are some minor omissions (see my answer). Additionally, it mentions how to set up the input text file in order to get the problematic input. As far as questions go in stating the complete code, this seems to be one of the better, if not the best ones.

Comment: @phihag: "All the code" isn't the same as an SSCCE (unfortunately, the new close reasons no longer include "too localized"/"not a real question").  This is a pet peeve of mine, I dislike questions of the form "here is my code, it doesn't work, what is wrong?".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The question clearly states that the output contains zeroes, although the input does not (and that is obviously wrong for a sorting algorithm). In the updated form, it even lists the specific output the program produces, and what is expected. How could this possibly be improved?

Comment: @phihag: SO isn't a debugging service ;) I would expect the OP to have done some rudimentary debugging to isolate *where* the behaviour diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your program only compiles/links when you ignore errors. Add `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc`, and remove the `getch` invocation as it's not needed for this example. Also, your `main` function is 1. *implicitely* returning int and 2. missing that return.

Your program fails in the merge step - you don't consider what happens when one of the arrays runs out before the other. The current progam just keeps on reading and grabs whatever is behind the `left` or `right` array, which is most often a zero.

What you want is to compare only while neither left or right is exhausted, and then just add the remaining values, like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(const int* left, const int* right, int* res, int n) {
    int i=0, j=0;
    while ((i < n/2) && (j < n - (n/2))) {
        if (left[i] < right[j]) {
            res[i+j] = left[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            res[i+j] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i < n/2) {
        res[i+j] = left[i];
        i++;
    }
    while (j < n-(n/2)) {
        res[i+j] = right[j];
        j++;
    }

    return res;
}

void _mergeSort(int* values, int* aside, int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    }
    _mergeSort(values, aside, n/2);
    _mergeSort(values+n/2, aside+n/2, n-(n/2));
    merge(values, values + n/2, aside, n);
    memcpy(values, aside, n * sizeof(int));
}

void mergeSort(int* values, int n) {
    int* aside = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    _mergeSort(values, aside, n);
    free(aside);
}

int main() {
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("prova.txt", "r");
    if (!input) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file");
        return 1;
    }

    int maximum_n = 100000;
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*maximum_n);
    int count;
    for (count = 0;count < maximum_n;count++) {
        if (fscanf(input, "%d", (array + count)) == EOF) {
            break;
        }
    }
    mergeSort(array, count);

    for(int k=0; k < count; k++) {
        printf("%d: %d \n", k, array[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that there is only one `malloc` call inside mergeSort now.

Answer (score 1):

Advice regarding optimization of memory used: 
 
1. If you want to allocate memory at every step (although this is is not necessary) make sure you free all the memory used when the temporary buffers are no longer needed. 
2. There is no need to create buffers at every step. You can allocate a buffer at the beginning and use pointers within that array at every step of the algorithm.

And the problem is with the merge function. When you were reaching the end of one of your arrays (right or left) you were pointing to memory that you did not allocate. There, it found the value 0 which was always smaller than the values in the array that was left. So, you have to stop merging when one of your buffers is copied completely in the result and then copy what is left of the other.

You should change it to this:

```
int *merge(int left[], int right[], int n){
  int *ordinato, i=0, j=0, k;
  ordinato = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  while((i<n/2) && (j<n-n/2)){
      if(left[i] < right[j]){
          *(ordinato+i+j) = left[i];
          i++;
      }else{
          *(ordinato+i+j) = right[j];
          j++;
      }
  }
  while(i!=n/2){
       *(ordinato+i+j) = left[i];
       i++; 
  }
  while(j!=n-n/2){
       *(ordinato+i+j) = right[j];
       j++; 
  }
  return ordinato;      
}
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, but you could explain what exactly was wrong with the `merge` function. Also, imho, `i < n/2` makes it more obvious what is happening here.

Comment: The problem was that when you were reaching the end of one of your arrays (right or left) you were pointing to memory that you did not allocate. There it found the value 0 which was always smaller than the values in the array that was left.
So, you have to stop merging when one of your buffers is copied completely in the result and then copy what is left of the other.

Comment: Yes, please add that to the answer ;) Note that I'm a fellow answerer, and not the questioner.