# trying this merge sort... but it's not working... can anyone find the error?

Tags: c, mergesort

I'm having a problem with a C program to perform a merge sort on a user-defined array. When I run the program, it's taking the array input, but it abruptly stops after that and shows error 255. This algorithm is from mycodeschool.org. Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void merge(int *a, int *left,int *right,int n, int ln, int rn)
{
int i,j,k;
i=j=k=0;
while(i<ln&&j<rn)
{
    if(left[i]<=right[j])
    {
        a[k]=left[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        a[k]=right[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
while(i<ln)
{
    a[k]=a[i];
    k++; i++;
}
while(j<rn)
{
    a[k]=a[j];
    k++; j++;
}

}
void mergesort(int *a, int n) // for partition
{
int mid,i,*left,*right;
if(n<=1)
  return;
mid=n/2;
left=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*mid);
right=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n-mid));
for(i=0;i<mid;i++)
  left[i]=a[i];
for(i=mid;i<n;i++);
  right[i-mid]=a[i];
mergesort(left,mid);
mergesort(right,(n-mid));
merge(a,left,right,n,mid,n-mid);
}
int main()
{
int *a,n,i;
printf("Enter the size of array: \t");
scanf("%d",&n);
a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
printf("\nEnter the array elements :\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  scanf("%d",(a+i));
mergesort(a,n);
printf("The sorted array is:\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  printf("%d",*(a+i));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have u made sure its a bug in the algorithm and not your dev environement setup ? See http://www.unixmen.com/fix-process-terminated-status-255-codeblocks/

Comment: prblem not solved still

Comment: Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minutes, 34 seconds)

Comment: Please indent the code.

Comment: Why is there malloc but no free?

Comment: i know that... free is not necessary here... anyways... there's the same error even after giving the free

Comment: can anyone just inform me what's wrong with the algorithm here ?????

Comment: `i know that... free is not necessary here...` why?

Comment: i guess giving free would not affect the algoritm... right?????

Comment: yes, but allocated memory should be free is good.

Comment: Also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513582/issues-writing-merge-sort-with-pointers-in-c?rq=1.

Comment: @user3513478 you are being a little rude here. We are not slaves to solve your problems. Also try some debugging yourself. You cannot develop anything without basic debugging skills (at least check your code with `printf`, it's simple...).

Answer (score 0):

shoud be

```
while(i<ln)
{
    a[k]=left[i];
    k++; i++;
}
while(j<rn)
{
    a[k]=right[j];
    k++; j++;
}
```

and

```
for(i=mid;i<n;i++);
```

remove `;`

Comment: oh sorry... I got my exam tomorrow... That's why i was anxious... Btw thanks a ton for the help